# Duplicate Files Copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE ERROR while using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to intergrate firebase in my App, i have included the dependancies but when i try to sync the project i get an error . Below is my gradle (Module:App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "oerrride.we.huzykamz.testingappfirebase"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is my  gradle (Project:AppName)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is the picture of my Error in Android studio[This is the Error shown click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Be8.png)

Comment: You can't mix the legacy SDK, `firebase-client-android:2.3.1`, with the libraries of the new 9.X SDK, such as `com.google.firebase:firebase-database`.

Comment: @qbix: you should write one definitive answer for this one, because you seem to be scooping them all up. :-)  Good work!

Comment: please at @qbix can you show me how to do that my editing my gradle , coz i ve tried and it failed

Comment: Try doing Build/Clean-Project before rebuilding.  You may also need to clean cache as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed  dependency  compile `'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'` because it was upgraded according to this link https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android , so it brought that error because there was a certain collision within the existing dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in gradle

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

Comment: which gradle file they are two @Bansal

Comment: I have added it there but it keeps bringing another error `Duplicate Files Copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE`

Comment: in Module:App build.gradle